# Adding second margin in pivot table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table created using pandas() looks like below:

```
Type    Type-1  Type-2  Type-3  Grand Total
product             
A           5   0           0   5
B           0   6           9   15
C           0   0           0   0
D           12  7           44  63
E           6   0           0   6
Deduction   0   0           9   9
H           50  6           8   64
I           0   0           0   0
Grand Total 73  19          70  162
```

Now I want to create a second margin called "W/O Deduction" which would basically subtract the value for deduction from the corresponding column. So the final result should be like this:

```
Type        Type-1  Type-2  Type-3  Grand Total
product             
A               5   0           0   5
B               0   6           9   15
C               0   0           0   0
D               12  7           44  63
E               6   0           0   6
Deduction       0   0           9   9
H               50  6           8   64
I               0   0           0   0
Grand Total     73  19          70  162
With DEDUCTION  73  19          61  153
```

How can I achieve this with panda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for new row filled by subtracted values of all columns by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with `fill_value=0` parameter for replace `NaN`s to `0` in counts:

```
df.loc['W/O DEDUCTION'] = df.loc['Grand Total'].sub(df.loc['Deduction'], fill_value=0)
#alternative
#df.loc['W/O DEDUCTION'] = df.loc['Grand Total'] - df.loc['Deduction']


print (df)
               Type-1  Type-2  Type-3  Grand Total
Type                                              
A                   5       0       0            5
B                   0       6       9           15
C                   0       0       0            0
D                  12       7      44           63
E                   6       0       0            6
Deduction           0       0       9            9
H                  50       6       8           64
I                   0       0       0            0
Grand Total        73      19      70          162
W/O DEDUCTION      73      19      61          153
```

Comment: @ jezrael by doing this getting the correct output, but only getting value where deduction value is present. I want to populate value where deduction value is equal to zero as well. For example for type-1, under "W/O DEDUCTION " row the value should be "73" not BLANK.

Comment: @ jezrael but when I am saving the pivot table to excel, getting blank value where deduction ==0

Comment: @greenking - Do you need `df.loc['W/O DEDUCTION'] = df.loc['Grand Total'].sub(df.loc['Deduction'], fill_value=0)` ?